# Laravel get group of arrays

Tags: php, laravel

I have code below and result is like:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "CPU" => "AMD a5"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "CPU" => "AMD a9"
  ]
]
```

I want to group them in same array like

```
CPU => [
"0" => "AMD a5",
"1" => "AMD a9"
]
```

## Code

```
$category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->where('status', '=', 'active')->first();
$products = $category->products;
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        foreach($product->attributes as $attribut){
            $attributes[] = [$attribut->group->title => $attribut->title];
        }
    }
```

What should I change?

Comment: What if `$attributes[] = $attribut->group->title => $attribut->title;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a bit of a more scalable solution where you might have multiple attribute types, the following may help:

```
$attributes = [
    [
        'CPU' => 'AMD A5'
    ],
    [
        'CPU' => 'AMD A9'
    ],
    [
        'GFX' => 'AMD'
    ]  
];

return collect($attributes)
    ->groupBy(function($item) {
        return key($item);
    })
    ->map(function($item) {
        return array_flatten($item); 
    })
    ->toArray();
```

The output of the above will be:

```
array:2 [▼
  "CPU" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "AMD A5"
    1 => "AMD A9"
  ]
  "GFX" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "AMD"
  ]
]
```

Here's an [example](https://implode.io/vf5aT0) you can play with.

Comment: Exactly the kind of results i want, i will try this and let you know thanks

Comment: Sounds good. You can also chain a `toArray()` if you want the results to be an array.

Comment: Just to know, if i want try array function where should i add toArray?

Comment: this does work so is the `Kelvin` answer first part.

Answer (score 1):

if your `$attribut->group->title` is "CPU" and your `$attribut->title` is "AMD a5"

then you can use this

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    foreach($product->attributes as $attribut){
        $attributes[$attribut->group->title][] =  $attribut->title;
    }
}
```

from **@mozammil** answer if you still wanna do using `foreach`

```
$attributes =
    [
        [
            'CPU' => 'AMD A5'
        ],
        [
            'CPU' => 'AMD A9'
        ],
        [
            'GFX' => 'AMD'
        ]
    ];
$data = [];
foreach ($attributes as $titles){
    foreach ($titles as $title=>  $row){
        $data[$title][] = $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, your first part does work for me just as `Mozammil` answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try collection methods here is an example.

```
$keyed = $collection->map(function ($item,$key) {
    return [[$key] => $item['CPU']];
});
```

For more information

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-map

Answer (score -1):

Use array_column to get one column of an array.

```
$category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->where('status', '=', 'active')->first();
$products = $category->products;
$cpu = array_column($products, "CPU");
```

This will return an array as your expected result.

https://3v4l.org/UYPhK

> This requires PHP 7 since in older versions array_column can't  handle objects

Comment: You mean like `[$attribut->group->title => array($attribut->title)]`?

Comment: No just as the code is written. No loops at all. Edited the answer

Comment: I don't get it, my `CPU` is dynamic name is not static. `my Cpu = $attribute->group->title`

Comment: In that case your question is unclear. Edit your question to make it more clear

Comment: I get what is the point of your solution but I'm afraid it isn't what I'm looking for, what I'm trying to do here is when I'm visiting category page get all attributes under that category products so nothing static here as cpu etc.

Comment: @mafortis that is not mentioned or shown in your question. Include all essential parts of your problem in your question.

Comment: Is not mentioned because i have that results (attributes of products in category) i just mentioned my problem part which is grouping my attributes